# Without connecting my phone via usb, is it possible to install an app I made on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, usb

I just bought a second hand phone and when I connected it to the computer it wasn't recognized (code 43). Since I really like the phone would it be possible for me to install apps I make on android studio another way than with an USB cable ? Like via wifi or something ?

Comment: email apk file to your own hotmail account...then from hotmail app install in your mobile, download the apk file and install it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Build your .apk
2. Download the .apk to the phone
3. Run the .apk

You can use an app like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), which allow you to access shared files on your network.

Comment: Regarding the 'download .apk to phone', you can do things like attach an .apk to an email (just click the attachment to install) or use an application that can push files to your phone from your PC, such as Pushbullet.

Comment: OK. but make sure you are allowed to install APK from unknown sources. Go to Settings > Install from Unknown Sources.

Answer (score 2):

> http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless

You can connect to ADB over the network.

Comment: Yes, but on most devices you need ADB over USB to activate that.

Answer (score 0):

sure!, are 2 ways to this, using wifi like you say, 1 is with root and the other is without root.

1.- Root:  need a app like "adb over wifi" [LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb&hl=es) i use the adb over wifi widget, anyway, the app give you a ip, so, in your pc/lap go to the location of your adb something like "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools" using cmd and enter adb connect ipcellphone:port thats all

2.- Without root need a specific app called "ADB Wireless (no-root)" [LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sherdle.adbwireless&hl=es) and follow the instructions, BUT need to plug in your cellphone 1 time (first use) but just one time is better than using the cellphone everytime.

see ya!